# Can't get cqlsh to run

Tags: cassandra, cqlsh

I've installed DSE 5.1.10 + the DSE demos as per [these](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/5.1/dse-admin/datastax_enterprise/install/installDEBdse.html) instructions on ubuntu.
Apparently it doesn't come with cqlsh so I went about installing it myself.
I've tried various methods the latest of which being

```
pip3 install cqlsh
```

this completed successfully and I can now run

```
cqlsh -version
```

and get

```
cqlsh 5.0.1
```

when running

```
cqlsh
```

I get the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/dsecqlsh.py", line 510, in <module>
    cqlsh.main(*cqlsh.read_options(sys.argv[1:], os.environ))
  File "/usr/bin/cqlsh.py", line 2447, in main
    encoding=options.encoding)
  File "/usr/bin/dsecqlsh.py", line 383, in __init__
    connect_timeout=connect_timeout)
  File "/usr/bin/cqlsh.py", line 528, in __init__
    self.get_connection_versions()
  File "/usr/bin/cqlsh.py", line 645, in get_connection_versions
    if result['dse_version']:
KeyError: 'dse_version'
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I'm curious as to your source of information that says DSE does not include the `cqlsh` command line. As far as I am aware all versions of DSE will install this.

To me it looks like you have clobbered your cqlsh install with the `pip3 install` command. You've likely installed the OSS version of cqlsh, hence the error complaining about the `dse_version` above.

I would say at first try uninstalling the pip3 version and see if that helps and then uninstall DSE and reinstall.

Comment: so, at first I followed the instructions and left out the optional dse-demo pack. there was no mention anywhere on the system of cqlsh which I thought was strange and sounded wrong. 

I assumed that perhaps it was left out intentionally so I then started looking around at installing cqlsh separately which i think is why I'm in the mess I'm in now.

Comment: @Blootac - right ok so I'm going to assume you didn't install `dse-full`. This is probably why things went wrong here. I never do anything aside from `dse-full` unless I'm installing an older version as per that docs page and even then will include all packages.

Comment: Yeah, I installed dse-full as per the instructions. Interestingly someone else at work at exactly the same problem... I got it to work by downloading the binaries and following the generic Linux installation instructions in the end.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what was wrong, resorted to removing everything and installing from tarball instead following https://docs.datastax.com/en/install/doc/install60/installTARdse.html